# How do I get a matching theme when I run a program as root?

Tags: themes, gtk

I use a Metacity theme in my Ubuntu installation. Unfortunately, it isn't activated for programs with GUI that are started as root user and some other other certain programs like `gufw`. When I start `gufw` by command-line not as root, it uses an old, not very attractive theme.

For example, `gufw` gives the following output from the command-line:

```
/usr/share/themes/Finery/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:365: error: unexpected number `0', expected number (float)
/usr/share/themes/Finery/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:365: error: unexpected number `0', expected number (float)
```

What could be the reason for this issue? Is there a way to enable this theme for these other programs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Themes you install via GNOME Appearance Settings reside in ~/.themes - your own home directory, where root won't be looking for them. You'll notice that themes that are installed system-wide (like ambiance/radiance) work fine, since those live in /usr/share/themes

To fix the issue, open your terminal and type

```
sudo ln -s ~/.themes /root/.themes
```

That way, root and your normal user will share the theme directory and everything will look the same.

Comment: does this covers also the theme customizations that you can change with GTK-Chtheme?

Comment: @NES: Probably not, since the customizations are stored in gconf2 settings database, and that is per-user storage. But at least all themes installed by user would be avaliable to root as well. And root can customize them (just open Appearance as root)

Comment: If you use a custom interface font, you can do the same with the `.local/share/fonts` directory in order to get the same fonts too

Answer (score 2):

Do a

`$ sudo ln -s ~/.themes /root`

This symlinks your theme directory so it can be used by the superuser account. Now any application run as root (or sudo/gksudo) will use your selected theme.

Comment: does this covers also the theme customizations that you can change with GTK-Chtheme?

Comment: that command will link your theme folder to root's **home folder**. That will NOT work!

Comment: Also, when you are creating symlinks you should provide full paths. A good tip is to use `ln -s 'readlink -f ./relative/path' /desired/symlink/path` where the single quotes around the `readlink` command should be backticks (couldn't find a way to override them). The `readlink -f` command gets the absolute path of a given reachable relative path.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution.

> 1. Open HOME folder
> 2. Show hidden files
> 3. Make a link for the .theme folder
> 4. Open Nautilus as root - ALT + F2 then enter GKSU NAUTILUS
> 5. Navigate to Root Home folder
> 6. Show hidden files
> 7. Move link to .theme folder into Root Home folder
> 8. Rename folder to .theme

close Root Nautilus and re-open

Or

Open terminal:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.fonts /root/.fonts  

sudo ln -s ~/.icons /root/.icons

sudo ln -s ~/.themes /root/.themes
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure your theme and icon theme is in the "/usr/share/themes/"  and "/usr/share/icons/" directory. You can do this by:
`sudo cp -r /home/jeroen/.themes/YOURTHEME/ /usr/share/themes/

sudo cp -r /home/jeroen/.icons/YOURICONTHEME/ /usr/share/icons/`
Change YOURTHEME/YOURICONTHEME to the theme/icontheme you want root programs to use.
If you want to make all icons/themes availlable for root use:
`sudo cp -r /home/jeroen/.themes/*/ /usr/share/themes/

sudo cp -r /home/jeroen/.icons/*/ /usr/share/icons/`
Then open gnome-appereance manager as root. Type in terminal:
`sudo gnome-appearance-properties`
Choose the theme of your choosing and from now on all programs excecuted as root will use that theme.