# Set a specific theme for root launched applications

Tags: gtk, root, themes

I would like the the applications I launch as root to look differently from the application launched as a normal user.

This can be done by using a theme that does not come from `usr/share/themes` but I haven't found a way to modify the default theme the root applications use.

Can this be done?

*Using `sudo gnome-appearance-properties` doesn’t work.*

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19313/how-do-i-get-a-matching-theme-when-i-run-a-program-as-root

Comment: `sudo gnome-tweaks` didnt work either on 20.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a hack to get get a system wide change :)

- From the **Appearance Preferences** choose a theme you have installed in ~/.themes
- Make a **.themes** folder in **/root** :

`sudo mkdir /root/.themes`

- Copy your theme to **/root/.themes** :

`sudo cp -r ~/.themes/yourTheme /root/.themes`

- Delete the **gtk-2.0** and **metacity-1** folders in **/root/.themes/yourTheme** :

`sudo rm -R /root/.themes/yourTheme/gtk-2.0 /root/.themes/yourTheme/metacity-1`

- Copy the **gtk-2.0** and **metacity-1** folders of the new root theme to **/root/.themes** :

`sudo cp -r /PathToRootTheme/gtk-2.0 /root/.themes/yourTheme/ ; sudo cp -r /PathToRootTheme/metacity-1 /root/.themes/yourTheme/`

Comment: What folder do you mean exactly by `/PathToRootTheme/`? You mean the one that was originally downloaded?

Comment: this works on 20.04? they keep changing these folders..

Answer (score 5):

You are right when you found out that applications launched as root adopt the theme of the user that invokes them.

However there are few applications only that make sense to be launched as root. Fortunately for me these are three applications only:

- **Gedit**
- **Nautilus**
- **Terminal**

All these three applications can at least partly be themed independent of the desktop theme. Once they are issued as root changes to the theme can be applied and will be kept:

[image]

<sup>Left: default themes | right: root themes</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot the only programs I really wanted with a different theme are gedit and nautilus. I won't accept your answer yet hopping someone has a system wide answer.

Comment: That was a creative workaround. +1

Comment: @danjjl: I'd love to see a better solution too ;)

Comment: found a way to get a system wide change :)

Comment: how can we do this??

Answer (score 2):

I used a different approach. I use per-user themes and icons for the normal user. These are at **~/.themes** and **~/.icons**. My methods involve tricking the root apps into thinking that they're using current user's **local theme**,but in fact uses another **global theme**.

### **Method 1** : Using a **systemwide/global theme and icons** for Root Apps

**Step 1** : Create symlinks in /root/.themes and /root/.icons to the global theme and icon you wish to use for root apps. Make **/root/.themes** and **/root/.icons** folders if they don't exist already:

```
sudo mkdir /root/.themes
sudo mkdir /root/.icons
```

I use the default Ubuntu Theme(**Ambiance**) and Icons(**ubuntu-mono-dark**).Replace **Ambiance** and **ubuntu-mono-dark** with the theme and icons you wish to use, and run
the following commands:

```
sudo ln -s -t /root/.themes /usr/share/themes/Ambiance
sudo ln -s -t /root/.icons /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
```

But make sure that the theme and icon are available at **/usr/share/themes** and **/usr/share/icons**,or else Root Apps won't be able to access them and they'll look ugly.

*Note:* The previous answers involved copying the entire theme and icon folders to /root/.themes and /root/.icons. A similar approach is used in **Method 2** of this answer. But,i prefer symlinks as they avoid data duplication and gets the job done.

**Step 2** : Rename the theme and icon symlinks in /root/.themes and /root/.icons to **exactly** the same name as the one from **~/.themes** and **~/.icons** that you're currently using. As i'm using **Delorean Dark** theme and **Faenza-Darkest** icons,the commands in my case would be:

```
sudo mv /root/.themes/Ambiance '/root/.themes/Delorean Dark'
sudo mv /root/.icons/ubuntu-mono-dark '/root/.icons/Faenza-Darkest'
```

Replace **Delorean Dark** and **Faenza-Darkest** with the names of the themes you use.

**Shortcut Command:** You may perform Step 1 and 2 in 1 step

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Ambiance '/root/.themes/Delorean Dark'
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark '/root/.icons/Faenza-Darkest'
```

### **Method 2** : Theme and Icons exclusively for Root Apps

If you wish to make Root App themes and icons not accessible to normal users,don't place them in **/usr/share/themes** and **/usr/share/icons**. Instead, place them in **/root/.themes** and **/root/.icons**. Then rename them to the same name as your current theme and icons, similar to **Step 2** of **Method 1**.

Answer (score 1):

There is more simpler solution.

Go to one of the tty's (by clicking on Ctrl+Alt+F3 or Ctrl+Alt+F4 or Ctrl+Alt+F5 for example). Login as 'root'.
type :

`startx`

Now you are logged as root into graphical mode, search the 'tweak' application and check the dark mode, logout. After you are back to the tty command line type:

`exit`.

To return to your session try clicking (Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F7)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the "ln -s -t..." tip -- I had forgotten about that.  That will be a big space-saver for sure.

In my case, I've always been a big fan of Shiki-Colors (and any subsequent themes based on them, including a few I've created) and GNOME-Colors.  Being a user of LXDE/Openbox, I've always felt that PCManFM doesn't visually do enough to adequately remind users when they're using it with sudo privileges.  Therefore, I've always thought that it and everything else should use the red (wine) GTK and icon themes when using it with sudo privileges.