# Ugly application GUI when logged in as root

Tags: themes, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a matching theme when I run a program as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19313/how-do-i-get-a-matching-theme-when-i-run-a-program-as-root)

When logging in as root all windows look very basic, much like windows 98, when using custom themes.

Themes in the Home/.theme folder are ignored and the root defaults back to a basic theme.

Ubuntu 11.10 + Ubuntu 12.04

This effects synaptic package manager, as well as nautilus. Seems to effect when logged on to any app as root...

http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2481/3894493076_4b3c63c9f0.jpg

Thanks